# Does the Google Chrome browser spy on users?

Tags: security, software

There are a number of places that claim that Google Chrome spies on its users:

1. [Is Google Chrome spying on its users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646188/is-google-chrome-spying-on-its-users)
2. [Google Chrome browser is spying all of us](http://surferzworld.com/2010/01/google-chrome-browser-spying/)
3. [Does Google Chrome spy on users?](http://forums.techarena.in/technology-internet/1298594.htm)

I'm not so concerned about individual web sites doing tracking (even supercookies and such), and google tracking all of my searches (I think those are a given).  What I'd really like to know is if I change the default search engine (and don't use google.com), does Chrome send information about the searches I do and the sites I visit back to Google?

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any specific claim to investigate. The term "spy on users" is vague. Each of the three example sites is talking about different aspects of privacy, and none relate to your speculation.

Comment: As a skeptic, I think everything you do online is being tracked.

Comment: Short answer: yes. you can verify with a packet sniffer like wireshark that chrome calls home regularly as you visit non-google websites.